# import RDS file stored online in the Open Science Framework

Tags: r

I am trying to open a .rds file that is stored on the Open Science Framework: https://osf.io/4z7mb

I'd like to open this file in R and I've tried a few different options, but neither have worked. Has anyone opened one of these files before?

**Attempt #1: using functions in the `osfr` package**

```
library(osfr)
test <- osf_retrieve_file("4z7mb") %>% osf_download()

Error: Authentication credentials were not provided.
       HTTP status code 401.
```

**Attempt #2: using option on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is-there-any-way-to-directly-access-data-files-in-the-Open-Science-Framework-from-R)**

```
require("httr")
url <- "https://osf.io/4z7mb//?action=download"
filename <- "AtlanticSalmonMeanForkLength.rds"
GET(url, write_disk(filename, overwrite = TRUE))
test <- readRDS(filename)

Error in readRDS(filename) : unknown input format
```

**Attempt #3: a similar [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138822/import-rds-file-from-github-into-r-windows) question & answer**

```
osfURL <- ("https://osf.io/4z7mb//?action=download")
download.file(osfURL,"AtlanticSalmonMeanForkLength.rds", method = "curl")
test <- readRDS("AtlanticSalmonMeanForkLength.rds")

Error in readRDS("AtlanticSalmonMeanForkLength.rds") : 
  unknown input format
```

Comment: When I click that link I get "Page not found". Are you sure that's the right page?

Comment: When using `osrf`, have you authenticated to the service in R? See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osfr/vignettes/auth.html

Comment: You are using a different ID for attempt 2. It seems that file is not an rds file. It's a CSV like file. That can be read with `require("httr");url <- "https://osf.io/gdr4q//?action=download";filename <- "data.csv";GET(url, write_disk(filename, overwrite = TRUE));data <- read.csv(filename, sep=";")`

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks for the helpful comments! 1) I do not have an authenticated personal access token that I'm using because I'm trying to make the script usable to anyone. Sounds like Option #1 probably isn't a good idea for that focus. 2) You're right, I forgot to change the link in Option #2 to match #1 and #2, I will correct that now.

Comment: I still have the problem that when I click https://osf.io/d4a3u I get "page not found" It doesn't look like that dataset exists, or maybe you need to be logged in (authenticated) to access it. Not sure because I don't have an account there. But if you need to be logged in to see it, then anyone else that needs to access it will need to authenticate as well.

Comment: @MrFlick I'm not sure why you can't see the file. The permissions on the project have been set to public.  I'll have to reach out to OSF to figure out why it's not available.

Comment: @MrFlick I got a quick response from OSF and the data should now be visible.

Answer (score 0):

There were backend issues with OSF that have now been corrected. Option #2 now works:

```
require("httr")
url <- "https://osf.io/4z7mb//?action=download"
filename <- "AtlanticSalmonMeanForkLength.rds"
GET(url, write_disk(filename, overwrite = TRUE))
test <- readRDS(filename)
```